# How to use Kubectl commands to Acess a Rancher Cluster through Ansible

Tags: kubernetes, ansible, cloud, rancher

I am currently developing a project where I need to get the pod names of a Kubernetes Cluster running on Rancher using Ansible. The main thing here is that I have a couple of problems that are preventing me from advance.
I am currently executing a playbook to try to retrieve this information, instead of running a CLI command, because I want to manipulate those Rancher machines later one (e.g. install an rpm file).
Here is the playbook that I am executing tot try to retrieve the pods' names from Rancher:

```yaml
---

- hosts: localhost
  connection: local
  remote_user: root
  roles:
    - role: ansible.kubernetes-modules
    - role: hello-world
  vars:
    ansible_python_interpreter: '{{ ansible_playbook_python }}'

  collections:
    - community.kubernetes

  tasks:
    -
      name: Gather openShift Dependencies
      python_requirements_facts:
        dependencies:
        - openshift

    -
      name: Get the pods in the specific namespace
      k8s_info:
        kubeconfig: '/etc/ansible/RCCloudConfig'
        kind: Pod
        namespace: redmine
      register: pod_list

    -
      name: Print pod names 
      debug:
         msg: "pod_list: {{ pod_list | json_query('resources[*].status.podIP')  }} "

    - set_fact:
        pod_names: "{{pod_list|json_query('resources[*].metadata.name')}}"
```

The problem is that I am getting a Kubernetes module error each time I am trying to run the playbook:

```
ERROR! the role 'ansible.kubernetes-modules' was not found in community.kubernetes:ansible           .legacy:/etc/ansible/roles:/home/jcp/.ansible/roles:/usr/share/ansible/roles:/etc/ansible/           roles:/etc/ansible

The error appears to be in '/etc/ansible/GetKubectlPods': line 7, column 7, but may
be elsewhere in the file depending on the exact syntax problem.

The offending line appears to be:

  roles:
    - role: ansible.kubernetes-modules
      ^ here
```

If I remove that line on the code, Where I try to retrieve that role, I still get a similar error:

```
An exception occurred during task execution. To see the full traceback, use -vvv. The error was: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'kubernetes'
fatal: [localhost]: FAILED! => {"changed": false, "error": "No module named 'kubernetes'", "msg": "Failed to import the required Python library (openshift) on localhost.localdomain's Python /usr/bin/python3.6. Please read module documentation and install in the appropriate location. If the required library is installed, but Ansible is using the wrong Python interpreter, please consult the documentation on ansible_python_interpreter"}
```

I have already tried to install ansible-galaxy kubernetes module on the machine and openshift.
Not sure what I am doing wrong since there are so many possibilities for what could be going wrong here.

Ansible Version Output:

```
ansible 2.9.9
  config file = /etc/ansible/ansible.cfg
  configured module search path = ['/home/jcp/.ansible/plugins/modules', '/usr/share/ansible/plugins/modules']
  ansible python module location = /home/jcp/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/ansible
  executable location = /home/jcp/.local/bin/ansible
  python version = 3.6.8 (default, Nov 21 2019, 19:31:34) [GCC 8.3.1 20190507 (Red Hat 8.3.1-4)]
```

I've debugged my python_required_info output from openshift dependencies and this is what I have:

```
ok: [localhost] => {
    "openshift_dependencies": {
        "changed": false,
        "failed": false,
        "mismatched": {},
        "not_found": [],
        "python": "/usr/bin/python3.6",
        "python_system_path": [
            "/tmp/ansible_python_requirements_info_payload_5_kb4a7s/ansible_python_requirements_info_payloa            d.zip",
            "/usr/lib64/python36.zip",
            "/usr/lib64/python3.6",
            "/usr/lib64/python3.6/lib-dynload",
            "/home/jcp/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages",
            "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages",
            "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/openshift-0.10.0.dev1-py3.6.egg",
            "/usr/lib64/python3.6/site-packages",
            "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages"
        ],
        "python_version": "3.6.8 (default, Nov 21 2019, 19:31:34) \n[GCC 8.3.1 20190507 (Red Hat 8.3.1-4)]"            ,
        "valid": {
            "openshift": {
                "desired": null,
                "installed": "0.10.0.dev1"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks for your help in advance!

Comment: Ansible version ? Please don't reply in a comment, edit your answer.

Comment: Added my Ansible Version output, thank you for your comment!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Edit*: The below answer was given for OP's specific Ansible version (i.e. 2.9.9) and is still valid if you still use it. Since version 2.10, you also need to install the relevant ansible collection if not already present

```
ansible-galaxy collection install kubernetes.core
```

See [the latest module documentation](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/kubernetes/core/k8s_info_module.html#ansible-collections-kubernetes-core-k8s-info-module) for more information

---

In Ansible 2.9.9, you're not supposed to do anything special to use the module **except installing the needed python dependencies**. See [the module documentation for your Ansible version](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.9/modules/k8s_info_module.html)

1. remove the line `- role: ansible.kubernetes-modules`, unless it is a module of yours in which case you have to tell us more because this is not a correct declaration.
2. remove the collection declaration
3. Add the following task somewhere before using the module:

   ```yaml
   - name: Make sure python deps are installed
     pip:
       name: openshift
   ```

Your actual `python_requirement_facts` task is doing nothing else than reporting the dependency is not found. Register the result and debug it to see for yourself.

Now use the `k8s_info` module normally.

Comment: Already removed that, thank you.
When I try to use the k8s_info module, I get the output that I printed on the thread:

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'kubernetes'
fatal: [localhost]: FAILED! => {"changed": false, "error": "No module named 'kubernetes'", "msg": "Failed to import the required Python library (openshift) on localhost.localdomain's Python /usr/bin/python3.6.....

Comment: what do you have in your your `hello-world` role ?

Comment: Pretty much nothing already removed it from the code! IHe keeps asking for a Kubernetes module that I don't know where to find...

Comment: When I add that pip install openshift line, It crashes ansible because I already have openshift installed. I have added my debug result to the main thread, which seems to make things even weird because it shows everything is as it should be.
Thank you for your time sir.

Comment: If it crashes, you have an other problem. `pip` module is idempotent. If the  python module is already there it just reports 'ok'. This module is needed on the machine executing the playbook. So you don't actually have to add it to your playbook if it targets a remote host. Installing it manually in the correct python version is enough.

Comment: Removing my pip installation and reinstalling should be enough?

Comment: It can help if your current install is in an instable state.